# How do you assert a String in Capybara?

Tags: string, json, selenium, capybara, assertion

I am testing an API call to the server using Cucumber + Capybara with Selenium WebDriver.
I managed to get the response obj, but how do you assert that the response body contains
certain String? For example if the response body contains "Hello World" I want to assert that
this response body (Which is string) contains a pattern "World"

ex. Something like:

> response = http.request(request)
>   response.body.should
>   have_text("World")

Alternatively is there a way to get "application/json" from the response and assert the contents using
Capybara?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your looking for is `have_content`.

```
response.body.should have_content("World")
```

For more info, check out the README: Check out the documentation: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara